# Running mysql_upgrade in Docker?

Tags: mysql, docker

I was trying to create a user using:

```
docker exec -i database mysql -uroot -proot -e "CREATE USER 'dbadmin'@'%'"
```

However I ran into this ERROR:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'password_last_changed' in 'mysql.user'
```

Answer (score 17):

After googling for a few hours, I found the answer in this [blog post](http://blog.achfrag.net/2016/04/13/updating-a-docker-container-with-mysql/):

```
docker exec -it container_name bash -c "mysql_upgrade -uroot -proot"
```

`root` must be your mysql username and password

Comment: This works for mariadb as well - note for nextcloud (start with docker-compose): the root password is defined in the compose file, and it is not the default

Comment: web archive link for the blog post: https://web.archive.org/web/20160827004503/http://blog.achfrag.net/2016/04/13/updating-a-docker-container-with-mysql/

Comment: How do I find my root password if `MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=yes`?