# Unable to start MySQL Server 'has length mismatch in the column name table_name'

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run the MySQL Server after importing a big database file 32 GB `length mismatch in the column name`

MySQL 5.7 using rh-mysql57
After using the command to run the server I'm getting a success message saying

`/etc/init.d/rh-mysql57-mysqld restart`

```
Stopping rh-mysql57-mysqld:                                [  OK  ]
Starting rh-mysql57-mysqld:                                [  OK  ]
```

The i want to loggin to the `mysql` using mysql with/without password
i'm getting this error

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

This is the error.log

```
2019-06-19T13:24:05.489656Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/opt/rh/rh-mysql57/lib/mysql
2019-06-19T13:24:05.751511Z 0 [Note] /opt/rh/rh-mysql57/root/usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.24-log) starting as process 19830 ...
2019-06-19T13:24:05.816168Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2019-06-19T13:24:05.816207Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-06-19T13:24:05.816225Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-06-19T13:24:05.816240Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __sync_synchronize() is used for memory barrier
2019-06-19T13:24:05.816254Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2019-06-19T13:24:05.816268Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-06-19T13:24:05.818025Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-06-19T13:24:05.818276Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-06-19T13:24:05.821067Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 2G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2019-06-19T13:24:06.062258Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-06-19T13:24:06.095072Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2019-06-19T13:24:06.107846Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-06-19T13:24:06.275233Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-06-19T13:24:06.275514Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-06-19T13:24:06.360584Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-06-19T13:24:06.362431Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-06-19T13:24:06.362460Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-06-19T13:24:06.364052Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.24 started; log sequence number 322424549252
2019-06-19T13:24:06.364899Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/opt/rh/rh-mysql57/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2019-06-19T13:24:06.365282Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2019-06-19T13:24:06.366882Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190619 15:24:06
2019-06-19T13:24:06.381320Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_table_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade
2019-06-19T13:24:06.381431Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_index_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade
2019-06-19T13:24:06.387318Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2019-06-19T13:24:06.387370Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2019-06-19T13:24:06.398153Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-06-19T13:24:06.398250Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2019-06-19T13:24:06.399654Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2019-06-19T13:24:06.424466Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is not available.
2019-06-19T13:24:06.424509Z 0 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2019-06-19T13:24:06.424554Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2019-06-19T13:24:06.436535Z 0 [Note] Failed to start slave threads for channel ''
2019-06-19T13:24:06.449394Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2019-06-19T13:24:06.449666Z 0 [Note] /opt/rh/rh-mysql57/root/usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.24-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2019-06-19T13:24:07.101293Z 2 [Note] Access denied for user 'UNKNOWN_MYSQL_USER'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2019-06-19T13:24:36.051422Z 3 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

The problem as I understand is coming from here

```
2019-06-19T13:24:06.381320Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_table_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade
2019-06-19T13:24:06.381431Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_index_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade
```

I've tried to run `mysql_upgrade` and the result is

```
mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered an error and will not continue
```

Comment: How did you do the "importing a big database file 32 GB"? It looks a bit as if you copied files into/over the data directory (which is not what importing usually means).

Comment: To explain a little bit the situation we have two servers the first is production and the second is the test 
Usually, I use mysqldump to export the table from the production server as SQL file then to import it in the test server using mysqldump also, so i didn't copy past the database file

Comment: @Solarflare any suggestions ?

Comment: Well, in that case, it looks like you also imported the `mysql` database, overwriting your current `mysql` database (containing, amongst others, the user logins). Then, a prod user could work for the test server (apart from cerificates/ssl keys). You could check your dump script if it contains the mysql db. In that case, your best bet is probably to restore the `mysql` db from a backup of the test server, otherwise, especially if test/prod versions differ, this could lead to inconsistencies (like you are facing right now).

Comment: @Solarflare i restored the old files ```innodb_table_stats and innodb_index_stats``` ibd and frm and now trying to start mysql getting this error
```2019-06-20T15:17:49.352017Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.24 started; log sequence number 322424549428
2019-06-20T15:17:49.352663Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/opt/rh/rh-mysql57/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2019-06-20T15:17:49.353114Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2019-06-20T15:17:49.353359Z 0 [ERROR] unknown variable 'rpl_semi_sync_master_enabled=0'
2019-06-20T15:17:49.353399Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting```

Comment: Do not replace single files in the data directory. That's what I suspected you did in my first comment, expecting a broken db. Now you probably really got one. I meant that you a) verify you can login with a prod password and b) use this login to import mysql from a mysql dump you made of the test-mysql db, just like you did when you (probably) accidently imported the prod mysql-db into the test server. I'd probably just reset my testserver now from a backup and reimport the 32gb with just the db you want (or you directly restore the testserver from a prod dump).

Comment: @Solarflare no, I found the solution finally :) I didn't import these files from my db but I've regenerated them again I will post the solution it's very easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to an import conflict between MySQL tables from the production server and test server.

As the file was large so difficult to modify the contents of the SQL file.
So the `mysql` database was imported too.

### CAUTION BEFORE PROCESSING PLEASE BACKUP YOUR DATABASE!

The solution that worked for us is like the rest

1- Stop the mysql server

> ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-systemd.html

2-Added the following parameters to

```
/etc/my.cnf
```

> ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/system-schema.html

```
innodb_force_recovery = 1
skip-grant-tables
```

3- In the database directory, save the folder `mysql` copy the`mysql` folder and empty the contents

4- Then execute the command

```
bin\mysqld --initialize
```

> ref:
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization.html

5- At the end execute the command

```
bin\mysql_upgrade
```

> ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-upgrade.html

6- Start the mysql server again

> ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-systemd.html

Comment: got no mysql_upgrade, where to find that app?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue & error while working with docker.

```
docker exec -it container_name bash -c "mysql_upgrade -uroot -proot"
```

source: [Running mysql_upgrade in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981983/running-mysql-upgrade-in-docker)