# Receiving CTE syntax error with 10.1.48-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Tags: mariadb, common-table-expression, non-recursive

Beginner with MariaDB and trying to understand the syntax.  I’m trying to create the simplest example and then build from there.  Shouldn’t the following work?

```
with myCTE as 
  (SELECT 1 as MyNum, 'A' as MyChar  
  UNION  
  SELECT 2 as MyNum, 'B' as MyChar)  
SELECT *  
FROM myCTE
```

I’m looking at the following three references and believe that I am adhering to their approach:

1. https://www.mariadbtutorial.com/mariadb-basics/mariadb-cte/
2. https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cte/
3. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/non-recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/

I’m sure I’m missing something simple, but just can’t see it.
Using MariaDB and TablePlus on iPad and I get generic error message:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near `'myCTE as (` …
Thanks for the assistance… First question on Stackoverflow

Comment: Shouldn't it be tagged with `sql` too?

Comment: CTEs are available in Mariadb 10.2 . You may consider using subqueries or upgrading to continue with your query as is

Comment: Thanks ‘ggordon’ I just saw that when I went back to read.  Just started with Mariadb in docker on rpi..I’ll look into upgrading.

Comment: Thanks AnilGoyal… I will catch that next time.

Comment: Reference for Mariadb upgrade for anyone finding this in the future. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68308764/how-to-upgrade-mariadb-running-as-a-docker-container

Comment: Please don't submit questions about eoled MariaDB database versions. Upgrade to a more recent version and then check again and  reconsider to ask.